# Gradle daemon crashes on start with hs_log_pid####.log

Tags: java, gradle

Running Windows 7, Gradle 3.1, Java 1.8.0_121, and the gradle wrapper, the Gradle daemon crashes the JVM on startup (gradlew.bat [any task]).

Any ideas?

I've tried multiple JVMs, 32 and 64 bit. I've rebooted my system. This happens almost every time... however, occasionally, Gradle will startup. Perhaps 1 out of 30 times. I disabled my firewall.

The hs_log looks like this:

```
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\.gradle\daemon\3.1\hs_err_pid4968.log
#

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#

#  EXCEPTION_INVALID_HANDLE (0xc0000008) at pc=0x000000007793bd37, pid=4968, tid=0x000000000000134c

#

# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)

# Problematic frame:

# C  [ntdll.dll+0x4bd37]

#

# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

#

# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

#



---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------



Current thread (0x00000000021be000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4940, stack(0x00000000022c0000,0x00000000023c0000)]



siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000008



Registers:

RAX=0x0000000075ba1319, RBX=0x00000000000005d0, RCX=0x00000000023be070, RDX=0x000007fefd641873

RSP=0x00000000023be680, RBP=0x00000000023be948, RSI=0x0000000000000042, RDI=0x00000000021be1f8

R8 =0x00000000023be748, R9 =0x00000000023be948, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000213

R12=0x00000000000005d0, R13=0x0000000054804de8, R14=0x00000000023be948, R15=0x00000000021be000

RIP=0x000000007793bd37, EFLAGS=0x0000000000000200



Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000023be680)

0x00000000023be680:   00000000000005d0 0000000000000042

0x00000000023be690:   00000000021be1f8 000000000217fae0

0x00000000023be6a0:   00000000c0000008 0000000000000000

0x00000000023be6b0:   000000007793bd37 0000000000000000

0x00000000023be6c0:   0000000000000001 0000000061dd0923

0x00000000023be6d0:   00000000023be710 00000000021be000

0x00000000023be6e0:   00000000023be7a0 00000000021be000

0x00000000023be6f0:   00000000023be710 0000000000000001

0x00000000023be700:   0000000000000008 00000000021be000

0x00000000023be710:   00000000023be8d8 000000000294a65c

0x00000000023be720:   0000000054805760 00000000021be000

0x00000000023be730:   0000000000000001 00000000023be840

0x00000000023be740:   00000000c0000008 000007fefd641873

0x00000000023be750:   00000000ebb353e0 00000000c00cb660

0x00000000023be760:   00000000eac66c28 0000000061e058cb

0x00000000023be770:   0000000014700208 00000000776f1951 



Instructions: (pc=0x000000007793bd37)

0x000000007793bd17:   20 89 01 33 c0 89 41 04 48 89 41 08 48 8b 94 24

0x000000007793bd27:   c8 00 00 00 48 89 51 10 89 41 18 e8 d9 cb fc ff

0x000000007793bd37:   8b 84 24 c0 00 00 00 48 81 c4 c8 00 00 00 c3 90

0x000000007793bd47:   90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 





Register to memory mapping:



RAX=0x0000000075ba1319 is an unknown value

RBX=0x00000000000005d0 is an unknown value

RCX=0x00000000023be070 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

RDX=0x000007fefd641873 is an unknown value

RSP=0x00000000023be680 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

RBP=0x00000000023be948 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

RSI=0x0000000000000042 is an unknown value

RDI=0x00000000021be1f8 is an unknown value

R8 =0x00000000023be748 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

R9 =0x00000000023be948 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value

R11=0x0000000000000213 is an unknown value

R12=0x00000000000005d0 is an unknown value

R13=0x0000000054804de8 is pointing into metadata

R14=0x00000000023be948 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000021be000

R15=0x00000000021be000 is a thread





Stack: [0x00000000022c0000,0x00000000023c0000],  sp=0x00000000023be680,  free space=1017k

Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

C  [ntdll.dll+0x4bd37]

C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x1873]

C  [kernel32.dll+0x21951]

C  [java.dll+0xcc6c]

C  0x0000000002757f54



Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)

j  java.io.FileOutputStream.close0()V+0

j  java.io.FileOutputStream.access$000(Ljava/io/FileOutputStream;)V+1

j  java.io.FileOutputStream$1.close()V+4

j  java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V+121

j  java.io.FileOutputStream.close()V+58

j  java.io.FilterOutputStream.close()V+36

j  java.io.PrintStream.close()V+27

j  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.daemonStarted(Ljava/lang/Long;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/internal/remote/Address;Ljava/io/File;)V+30

j  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.doAction([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/launcher/bootstrap/ExecutionListener;)V+353

j  org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run([Ljava/lang/String;)V+12

v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0

j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100

j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6

j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56

j  org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V+147

j  org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V+3

j  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10

v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub



---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------



Java Threads: ( => current thread )

  0x00000000581e2800 JavaThread "Incoming local TCP Connector on port 49441" [_thread_in_native, id=2532, stack(0x00000000590d0000,0x00000000591d0000)]

  0x00000000583c0800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2804, stack(0x0000000058d10000,0x0000000058e10000)]

  0x00000000550ff000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=672, stack(0x0000000056a90000,0x0000000056b90000)]

  0x0000000056423800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2676, stack(0x0000000056fc0000,0x00000000570c0000)]

  0x0000000056422000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4172, stack(0x0000000056de0000,0x0000000056ee0000)]

  0x000000005641a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4724, stack(0x0000000056c90000,0x0000000056d90000)]

  0x0000000056419800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4712, stack(0x0000000056b90000,0x0000000056c90000)]

  0x0000000056416800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4376, stack(0x00000000568a0000,0x00000000569a0000)]

  0x00000000550df800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4580, stack(0x0000000056310000,0x0000000056410000)]

  0x0000000055098800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2364, stack(0x0000000055fe0000,0x00000000560e0000)]

=>0x00000000021be000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4940, stack(0x00000000022c0000,0x00000000023c0000)]



Other Threads:

  0x0000000055090800 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000561b0000,0x00000000562b0000] [id=5036]

  0x00000000564a5000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000057110000,0x0000000057210000] [id=1328]



VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)



VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None



Heap:

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 4069K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 9% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eac81460,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 98% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd78040,0x00000000ebd80000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 2224K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 5% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c022c240,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 9749K, capacity 9868K, committed 10112K, reserved 1058816K

  class space    used 1294K, capacity 1346K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K



Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011b00000,0x0000000011d10000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011500000



Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006252b6d0

 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012500000, 0x0000000013500000)

 End Bits:   [0x0000000013500000, 0x0000000014500000)



Polling page: 0x0000000000430000



CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3455Kb max_used=3455Kb free=242304Kb

 bounds [0x0000000002740000, 0x0000000002ab0000, 0x0000000011740000]

 total_blobs=1174 nmethods=838 adapters=249

 compilation: enabled



Compilation events (10 events):

Event: 0.984 Thread 0x0000000056423800  833       3       java.util.HashMap$HashIterator::nextNode (100 bytes)

Event: 0.984 Thread 0x0000000056423800 nmethod 833 0x0000000002a9ed90 code [0x0000000002a9ef40, 0x0000000002a9f418]

Event: 0.985 Thread 0x0000000056423800  834       3       java.lang.StringBuffer::<init> (7 bytes)

Event: 0.985 Thread 0x0000000056423800 nmethod 834 0x0000000002a9f650 code [0x0000000002a9f7c0, 0x0000000002a9fa70]

Event: 0.990 Thread 0x0000000056423800  835       3       java.util.Formatter$Flags::contains (22 bytes)

Event: 0.990 Thread 0x0000000056423800 nmethod 835 0x0000000002a9fb90 code [0x0000000002a9fd00, 0x0000000002a9ff10]

Event: 0.994 Thread 0x0000000056423800  836       3       java.lang.String::substring (56 bytes)

Event: 0.994 Thread 0x0000000056423800 nmethod 836 0x0000000002aa01d0 code [0x0000000002aa0360, 0x0000000002aa0708]

Event: 1.000 Thread 0x0000000056422000  837       4       sun.net.www.ParseUtil::encodePath (336 bytes)

Event: 1.009 Thread 0x0000000056423800  838  s    3       java.io.BufferedOutputStream::write (35 bytes)



GC Heap History (6 events):

Event: 0.402 GC heap before

{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 16384K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd80000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 6349K, capacity 6472K, committed 6528K, reserved 1056768K

  class space    used 802K, capacity 856K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Event: 0.406 GC heap after

Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 2534K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd79b30,0x00000000ebd80000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 813K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00cb660,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 6349K, capacity 6472K, committed 6528K, reserved 1056768K

  class space    used 802K, capacity 856K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

}

Event: 0.660 GC heap before

{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 18918K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd79b30,0x00000000ebd80000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 813K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00cb660,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 7027K, capacity 7192K, committed 7424K, reserved 1056768K

  class space    used 880K, capacity 924K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K

Event: 0.662 GC heap after

Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 2453K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 95% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebfe5578,0x00000000ec000000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd80000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 821K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00cd660,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 7027K, capacity 7192K, committed 7424K, reserved 1056768K

  class space    used 880K, capacity 924K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K

}

Event: 0.935 GC heap before

{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 18837K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 95% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebfe5578,0x00000000ec000000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd80000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 821K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 1% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c00cd660,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 9395K, capacity 9548K, committed 9856K, reserved 1058816K

  class space    used 1250K, capacity 1346K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K

Event: 0.938 GC heap after

Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):

 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 2528K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000ec000000, 0x0000000100000000)

  eden space 16384K, 0% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000ebb00000)

  from space 2560K, 98% used [0x00000000ebb00000,0x00000000ebd78040,0x00000000ebd80000)

  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)

 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 2224K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000c2b00000, 0x00000000eab00000)

  object space 44032K, 5% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000c022c240,0x00000000c2b00000)

 Metaspace       used 9395K, capacity 9548K, committed 9856K, reserved 1058816K

  class space    used 1250K, capacity 1346K, committed 1408K, reserved 1048576K

}



Deoptimization events (10 events):

Event: 0.634 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029bca3c method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 91

Event: 0.634 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029bca3c method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 91

Event: 0.724 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029973cc method=java.util.regex.Matcher.match(II)Z @ 86

Event: 0.724 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000002997490 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 75

Event: 0.724 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002a2f8cc method=java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;II)Ljava/lang/String; @ 8

Event: 0.732 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029973cc method=java.util.regex.Matcher.match(II)Z @ 86

Event: 0.793 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000298e9b8 method=java.util.HashMap.getNode(ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Node; @ 129

Event: 0.793 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000029bcce8 method=java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 203

Event: 0.864 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002a29ee0 method=java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; @ 128

Event: 0.876 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000029c1db8 method=java.lang.String.substring(I)Ljava/lang/String; @ 35



Internal exceptions (10 events):

Event: 0.306 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException': 40> (0x00000000eb4b57c0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\interpreterRuntime.cpp, line 366]

Event: 0.319 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb5a7f10) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.319 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb5a8be8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.332 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb6c42a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.333 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb6c7b18) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.333 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb6cc318) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.346 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb822f38) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.347 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb836388) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.347 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb837da0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Event: 0.348 Thread 0x00000000021be000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x00000000eb849b18) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]



Events (10 events):

Event: 1.001 loading class org/gradle/cache/internal/DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock$3

Event: 1.001 loading class org/gradle/cache/internal/DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock$3 done

Event: 1.001 loading class java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator

Event: 1.001 loading class java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator done

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/launcher/daemon/bootstrap/DaemonStartupCommunication

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/launcher/daemon/bootstrap/DaemonStartupCommunication done

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/process/internal/streams/EncodedStream$EncodedOutput

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/process/internal/streams/EncodedStream$EncodedOutput done

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/process/internal/streams/EncodedStream

Event: 1.002 loading class org/gradle/process/internal/streams/EncodedStream done





Dynamic libraries:

0x000000013f920000 - 0x000000013f957000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe

0x00000000778f0000 - 0x0000000077a9a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

0x00000000776d0000 - 0x00000000777ef000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll

0x000007fefd640000 - 0x000007fefd6aa000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

0x000007fefec50000 - 0x000007fefed2b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll

0x000007fefeb10000 - 0x000007fefebaf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll

0x000007feffbe0000 - 0x000007feffbff000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll

0x000007feff340000 - 0x000007feff46d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll

0x00000000777f0000 - 0x00000000778ea000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll

0x000007feff470000 - 0x000007feff4d7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll

0x000007feff790000 - 0x000007feff79e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll

0x000007fefedb0000 - 0x000007fefee7a000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll

0x000007fefc070000 - 0x000007fefc264000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll

0x000007fefebb0000 - 0x000007fefec21000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll

0x000007fefd9f0000 - 0x000007fefda1e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL

0x000007feffad0000 - 0x000007feffbd9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll

0x00000000644f0000 - 0x00000000645c2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll

0x0000000061d10000 - 0x00000000625ab000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

0x000007fef6340000 - 0x000007fef6349000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll

0x000007feff7a0000 - 0x000007feff7ed000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll

0x000007fefd9e0000 - 0x000007fefd9e8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll

0x000007fef77e0000 - 0x000007fef781b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll

0x000007fefc700000 - 0x000007fefc70c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll

0x0000000077ab0000 - 0x0000000077ab7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

0x00000000731f0000 - 0x00000000731ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\verify.dll

0x000000006d130000 - 0x000000006d159000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\java.dll

0x000000006d110000 - 0x000000006d126000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\zip.dll

0x000007fefda20000 - 0x000007fefe7aa000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll

0x000007feff580000 - 0x000007feff783000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll

0x000007fefd620000 - 0x000007fefd62f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll

0x0000000064690000 - 0x00000000646aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\net.dll

0x000007fefcdc0000 - 0x000007fefce15000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll

0x000007fefcdb0000 - 0x000007fefcdb7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll

0x0000000064670000 - 0x0000000064681000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\nio.dll

0x000007fefaff0000 - 0x000007fefb00e000     C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\.gradle\native\21\windows-amd64\native-platform.dll

0x000000006d100000 - 0x000000006d10d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\management.dll

0x000007fefce20000 - 0x000007fefce38000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll

0x000007fefcb20000 - 0x000007fefcb67000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll

0x000007fefd970000 - 0x000007fefd98e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll

0x000007fefd4c0000 - 0x000007fefd4cf000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll

0x000007fefb360000 - 0x000007fefb387000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL

0x000007fefb350000 - 0x000007fefb35b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL

0x000007fefb1e0000 - 0x000007fefb1f1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL

0x000007fefb1c0000 - 0x000007fefb1d8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL

0x000007fefa0c0000 - 0x000007fefa1e5000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll



VM Arguments:

jvm_args: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant 

java_command: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 3.1

java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.1-bin\1m9lcdug8d7sfm2g685md9alsf\gradle-3.1\lib\gradle-launcher-3.1.jar

Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD



Environment Variables:

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

CLASSPATH=C:\cygwin\home\jzwolak\files\code\processdb\processdb\application\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

USERNAME=Jason Zwolak

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\..\linux\compiler\lib\intel64_lin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.143\windows\tbb\bin\..\..\..\linux\tbb\lib\intel64\gcc4.7;

OS=Windows_NT

PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 70 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel







---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------



OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23572)



CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 70 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2



Memory: 4k page, physical 4193784k(2248400k free), swap 8385708k(6014520k free)



vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)



time: Thu Feb 23 09:55:18 2017

elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I restarted Windows 7 and the problem continued.

But when I restarted my host operating system (Mac OS X) and then started Windows 7 in VMware Fusion (which is where I was working all along), Gradle started.

I did have a Gradle daemon running on Mac OS X, I wonder if the Windows Gradle was detecting this and having some interaction with the Mac OS X Gradle daemon?

Anyway, rebooting the host and guest OSes fixed the problem. I also had to delete the daemon log files and registry in `c:\Users\My User Name\.gradle\daemon\3.1`

Answer (score -1):

***The Resource you are trying to build using Gradle it not being executed, as a result, the TaskRunner is failing to find the Resource, causing the error.*** Don't interrupt the build to ensure proper functioning of Gradle.Goggle has not been able to do off with this problem. So people don't prefer it. If you are using Android Studio (as me ) you cannot escape it. It will take off your life if a resource is not built while running. If you are not developing for Android. Please use batch files( Windows) or makefile (on Linux/Unix). you can use CMake (a cross-platform TaskRunner)

You can get it through the official site :: https://cmake.org/download/

its free and also better, best of luck.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I did in fact try to interrupt the build with Ctrl-C earlier in the day. Are you saying that this caused a problem?

Comment: It might be so. **plaese upvote my answer if you think it is a reasonable answer** it would add to my CV @Jason

Comment: I'm still unclear about what your answer is saying. And I ran the build today without having Ctrl-C'd an early build and Gradle crashed again. Rebooting my Windows operating system after deleting the registry fixed the problem.